# Replacing an asterisk to make the strings equal , but how?

Tags: c

I have to write a funcion that checks if two strings are equal. If so it returns 1 otherwise 0. But, if the second string contains a replaceable asterisk it will be replaced in order to make the strings equal.For example "main.c" and "*.c" are equal because "main" can be replace with "*". How do i implement this ? Using strcmp ?

Comment: Do you need to implement this yourself (i.e, for coursework), or can you use a C library function?

Comment: No not with strcmp. Actually quite a complicated problem. Work out an algorithm and then write the code.

Comment: An asterisk in the first string has special meaning? Can it appear at all? Is it matched with an asterisk in the second string ... and does that asterisk in the second string "expand"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23457543/971127

Comment: If there's only one asterisk, you just need to check that the chars before the asterisk match the first chars of the other string, and the chars after it match the last chars of the other string.  With more than one asterisk, it gets more difficult.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare strings with wildcard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23457305/compare-strings-with-wildcard)

Answer (score 4):

If you're allowed to use all C library functions, there's one that does this:

```
if (fnmatch("*.c", "main.c", 0)) {
    // it's a match
}
```

[See the manual page for details.](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fnmatch)

Comment: Notice that this POSIX function is not available on all implementations of the C programming language, for instance, Windows doesn't have it as far as I know.